# C# - data structure used for settings file

Tags: c#, data-structures, settings, implementation

Does `C#` offer something default to store application / any sort of settings?

I could use `Dictionary<K, T>`, but actually I would prefer some structure, which natively supports `xml` export / import and different other features, which aren't implemented in the `Dictionary` or other map-like collections.

*For example, in `C++` I would use `QSettings` in `Qt` or something like `boost::property_tree` if using `boost`.*

If you have any ideas or good implementations, that would be great. Thank you.

Comment: App Settings as everyone else mentioned is what you want. Has a designer and an added benefit, you can set individual settings to be user specific or global.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want [`System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx), especially [`ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings.aspx), which is a [`System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

AppSettings sounds like it fits the bill:

http://odetocode.com/code/345.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think this is what you are looking for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4s6c3a0.aspx

Example of how it's used herE: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If [Properties.Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28VS.80%29.aspx) doesn't work for you, then you might just create your own class hierarchy of settings, and use simple XML serialization/deserialization to handle the file I/O. I find this much more flexible than .NET settings.